# Using FOR loop with Windows Command Line with multiple variables

Tags: windows, command-line, command

The basic question behind this post is there a way to specify two parameters in a FOR loop in the windows command prompt?

Specifically to my problem, I am using a simulation.exe that runs through the Windows command prompt. In it's simplest form, the program can be run using:

```
simulation.exe parameters.txt
```

Where the text file specifies file paths to multiple input files.

You can specify some parameters in line itself, while specifying others in the text file:

```
simulator.exe parameters.txt parameter1: filepath parameter2: filepath
```

This is useful for using the FOR loop, specifying all the parameters that remain constant within the text file and the parameters to vary in the line itself.

This is all quite simple thus far, but my problem comes when I need to loop with two parameters. I have a 100 sets of two matching .asc files, one for parameter 1 and the other for parameter 2.  I don't think it can be done simply using the FOR loop? I'm fairly new at this so as a long shot I tried & and > to  specify 2 parameters for one FOR loop:

```
for %x in (*parameter1.asc) & %y in (*parameter2.asc) DO (
simulation.exe parameters.txt parameter1: %x parameter: %y
)
```

Which was unsuccessful, as I'm sure most of you could immediately deduce.

Could anyone help me with a solution? I've tried to be as clear as possible, but please let me know if my explanation is lacking.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that I really understand your task...

But you can nest two for loops

```
for %x in (*parameter1.asc) DO (
  FOR %y in (*parameter2.asc) DO (
     simulation.exe parameters.txt parameter1: %x parameter: %y
  )
)
```

Don't forget to double the percent signs when this is used in a batch file

Comment: That's great, and I just want to clarify the data I'm working with to maybe make the questions more clear. I have 100 wind prediction scenarios, with each scenario consisting of a wind direction layer and a wind speed layer (ie parameter 1 and 2 generally referenced above). So when I run the loop, I need to run the simulation on each of the 100 matching pairs of wind data. Would the solution above do that? Or would it rather be splitting the pairs up and running say each wind direction layer with every one of the other 100 wind speed layers?